# node.js JSON Array, Promise Fucntion

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, promise

Obtain values in the form of a JSON array, apply the "AES256decrypt" function, and try to store the decoded values back in the JSON array. But the json values do not save normally. I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you handle it within the promise function? Or can you take the stored value out of the promise function?

Sample Data

```
[
  {
   "admin": Crytovalue1,
   "email": Crytovalue2,
   "name": Crytovalue3,
  },
  {
   "admin": Crytovalue4,
   "email": Crytovalue5,
   "name": Crytovalue6,
  }
]
```

What is the best way to decrypt all the values in the above JSON and maintain JSON structure.

```
 // my decrypt function
 var AES256decrypt = function (KeyValue) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var decrypt = ((encrypted) => {
                let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', ENC_KEY, IV);
                let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');

                return (decrypted + decipher.final('utf8'));
            });

            resolve(decrypt(KeyValue));
        });
    }
```

```
// my current attempt
if (rows) {
    var userinfoArray = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.rows.length; i++) {
        Promise.all([AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].admin), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].email), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].name)])
            .then(([adminDecrypt, emailDecrypt, nameDecrypt]) => {
                var userinfo = new Object();

                userinfo.admin = adminDecrypt;
                userinfo.email = emailDecrypt;
                userinfo.name = nameDecrypt;

                userinfoArray.push(userinfo);
            }).catch(callback);

        socket.emit('UserDataOK', userinfoArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `But the json values do not save normally`?

Comment: Are you sure you mean JSON? JSON is a string-based data interchange format. In JavaScript you parse JSON into a JavaScript object before you use it and then when you want to send/save that object again as JSON you will stringify it.

Comment: You need to do an outer `Promise.all()` on the results from the `for` loop.  You have no way of knowing when everything is done.  You're also calling `socket.emit()` inside the `for` loop which doesn't make much sense.  This might be simpler to code with `await`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you create a `Promise` inside of `AES256decrypt`?  The code inside of `new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { … })` is not asynchronous and in the way you use `AES256decrypt` in the loop,  you do gain anything by using a `Promise` within the `AES256decrypt` .

Comment: It seems that after trying many different methods, the socket.emit() left untouched. I don't know how to use await, but I will try to find it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not used to using promise. I used it as it is because I could get a good answer by looking for various kinds of answers